# Problem with mongodb installation on Raspberry PI 4 (bullseye)

Tags: linux, mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, bullseye

I have tried to install mongodb in a Raspberry PI 4 with Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and i have the following error:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian bullseye/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

Previously I installed it on a Raspberry PI with buster and it worked. But when I try to follow the same step on the Debian bullseye the above error occurs. I have tried to find the fix by searching the forums and trying to understand what happened, but I can't find the solution.

I have done this steps

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian bullseye/mongodb-org/6.0 main" | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

To give you more information these are the features of the raspberry:

cat /etc/os-release:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

uname --all:

```
Linux server1 5.15.61-v8+ #1579 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 26 11:16:44 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I have cross-compiled binaries for MongoDB 6.x and put them on [Github](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries). I am running them on a Raspberry Pi 4 at the moment. Feel free to raise an issue on the repo if you run into obstacles.

Comment: @MattKneiser you should turn that into a reply

Comment: It looks that the last supported version of `MongoDB`is the 4.4 (MongoDB forum to more [info](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/impossible-to-start-mongodb-ubuntu-server-20-04-03-lts-on-raspberry-pi-4/122345)).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not officially support the Raspberry Pi as of this writing. I have cross-compiled the latest source and posted the binaries on Github [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries/). You can raise an issue on that repo if you run into issues.